# What is disinheritance in object oriented programming?

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I am confused over Virtual Inheritance and disinheritance ? Is both are same ?

Comment: There's no such thing as "disinheritance."  [This patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US5758349) seems to have coined the term to describe a form of "monkey patching," but that appears to be the sole significant reference.

Comment: Where did you see the term "disinheritance"?  I've not previously come across that terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Virtual inheritance**

[Virtual inheritance](http://Virtual%20inheritance) is a technique to solve the problem of the [diamond of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) that can arise when via multiple inheritance you can inherit the same base class several times.

For example, suppose you have a class `Person`, and two derived classes of it: `Student` and `Employee`.  Now you can have a class `StudentWorker` that inherits from `Student` AND from `Employee`.  So this class inherits twice the class `Person`.  But in reality there should be only one `Person`, with a unique name and date of birth, etc... You can achieve this with virtual inheritance.

```
class Person {...};  
class Student: public virtual Person {...}; 
class Employee: public virtual Person {...}; 
class StudentWorker: public Student, public Employee {...};
```

**Disinheritance**

The idea of disinheritance is to [get rid of some inherited member](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Y7FwNB4GV4EC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=disinherit%20smalltalk&source=bl&ots=BXlCn9O8ny&sig=LaWYAjWUknrrk4i3ORoL0QPWwy8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLip6lycbNAhVhCcAKHTR4D-IQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=disinherit%20smalltalk&f=false).   The problem is that disinheritance would infringe the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and break core assumptions about derived objects.  This is certainly why it is not supported by modern mainstream OOP languages as far as I know (for example [Java](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8lBYrBKatRMC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=disinherit%20java&source=bl&ots=dmpiACatfq&sig=FviOkGMof0rJh-M2-iKg8wv66mM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjukMX2ycbNAhUiJ8AKHR8iB4sQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=disinherit%20java&f=false)).  (*there seems however to exist a patent for a [runtime implementation](https://www.google.com/patents/US6101501) of the concept*)

There are several strategies that can help to achieve the underlying need:

- A usual workaround is to override the function to be desinherited, and trigger an exception in case it is called.
- Another approach is to decompose what is inherited and (over)use multiple inheritance in combination with a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) architecture

Some will claim that the need for disinheritance is the symptom of a design flaw.  Alternatives to be considered:

- private inheritance, to hide the inheritance downstream the inheritance hierarchy.
- composition, using some proxy members to address the composed object  frequently does address such (des)inheritance problems, especially when the principle of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is not rigorously enforced.

**Similarities**

So in general, and in absence of an authoritative definition of the term, disinheritance has nothing to do with virtual inheritance.

However, the virtual inheritance can somehow be analyzed as a way of getting rid of multiple redundant base classes.  So I can imagine that in this very specific context, some people could consider it as a kind of disinheritance. Personally, I think this terminology would be abusive here, because it's not so about getting rid of the inheritance, but "factorizing" (in the mathematical sense) redundant base elements into a common base element.

Comment: is there a source that one can check for what "disinheritance" means? or is this the way how you personally interpret this term?

Comment: @gnat There are some questions around on SO in relation with C++, CSS, and other languages. It's a term which seems to be rooted in the Smalltalk terminology. It's used in articles, blogs and books for other languages as well ([F# example]( http://trelford.com/blog/post/Disinherited.aspx)).  So I didn't find a single authoritative definition of it, but all these sources are consistent on the use of this terms, so I build on it.  Of course, if OP gives is definition, I could fine tune on more specific meaning.